# weather information repeater use jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

am using jquery mobile for make weather app , i have some error withe code ,
i make table for weather information hourly  like this :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvCjV.jpg)

i want repeat only the information data not all table only `tbody` [mean this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkAXF.jpg)

code using

```
var html = '';

for (var h=0; h<24; h++) {

    var date = new Date(data.hourly.data[h].time * 1000);
     html += '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th>الرياح</th><th>درجة الحرارة</th><th>س</th></tr></thead>';
     html += '<tbody><tr class="success"><td>' + Math.round(data.hourly.data[h].windSpeed) + ' ' + 'km/h' + '</td><td>' + Math.round(data.hourly.data[h].temperature) + '&amp;deg;C' + '</td><td>' + date.getHours() + ':00' + '</td></tr></tbody></table>';

}

html += '</div>';

 $("#hourly").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question completely, but it seems you only want to create table rows inside the for loop. Is it correct?

Comment: @HectorBarbossa , yes repeat rows only